# Calling a method with ajax in aspx.cs from aspx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call a method from my aspx page. This method is found on the aspx.cs page, but it is throwing an error. Do you know what's wrong, please?

ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function OnSucceeded(response) {
         alert(response);
     }
     function OnFailed(error) {
         alert(error);
     }         //Default.aspx
     function insertMarker() {
         var usernameName = 'username';
         var usernameVal = document.getElementById('<%=hdnUsername.ClientID%>').value;

         var latitudeName = 'latitudeStr';
         var latitudeVal = document.getElementById('<%=hdnMarkerLatitude.ClientID%>').value;

         var longituteName = 'longitudeStr';
         var longitudeVal = document.getElementById('<%=hdnMarkerLongitude.ClientID%>').value;

         var iconName = 'markerIcon';
         var iconVal;
         if (document.getElementById('blueMarker').checked) {
             iconVal = 'images/blueMarker.png';
         }
         if (document.getElementById('greenMarker').checked) {
             iconVal = 'images/greenMarker.png'
         }
         if (document.getElementById('pinkMarker').checked) {
             iconVal = 'images/pinkMarker.png';
         }

         var titleName = 'name';
         var titleVal = document.getElementById('<%=title.ClientID%>').value;

         var descriptionName = 'description';
         var descriptionVal = document.getElementById('<%=description.ClientID%>').value;

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "mapping.aspx/insertNewMarker",
             data: {"username" : usernameVal, "longitudeStr":longitudeVal, "latitudeStr" :latitudeVal, "markerIcon":iconVal, "name" : titleVal, "description" :descriptionVal},
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             dataType: 'json',
             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
             },
             success: function (result) {
                 alert("We returned: " + result.d);
             }
         });
     }

     </script>
```

Website Design
    
        
            
            
                Save Marker
                Title
                
                Description
                
                
                      
                  
                
                    
                    
                    
                    
                
                
                Save

Aspx.cs Method.

```
[ScriptService]
public partial class mapping: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    private static void insertNewMarker(string username, string longitudeStr, string latitudeStr,  string markerIcon, string name, string description)
    {

       //My Code
    }


}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: A 500 error doesn't really say much. Do you get an error if you breakpoint in your code?

Comment: You want us to debug your code, but you have not supplied your code nor any useful error! Use a tool like fiddler to inspect the network traffic which will give more information on the error. That or set a break point on your webmethod and step through tat to find your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server-side webmethod cannot be *private*, you have to change it to *public*.

From [MSDN documentation on webmethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ef803zd(v=vs.90).aspx):

> When you create a Web service in managed code, you indicate the
>   methods that are available through that Web service by placing the
>   WebMethod attribute before the method declaration of a *Public* method.
>   *Private* methods cannot serve as the entry point for a Web service
>   although they can be in the same class and the Web service code can
>   call them.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `data` like this

```
data:JSON.stringify({username : usernameVal, longitudeStr:longitudeVal, latitudeStr :latitudeVal, markerIcon:iconVal, name : titleVal, description :descriptionVal}),
```

You need to pass data as `json stirng` which has a specific format. If you use `JSON.stringify` data will be convetred to json string and if you don't use this than you have to pass `every paremter and its value in quotes` like this.

```
data:"{username:'" + usernameVal + "',............}",
```

Comment: thank you changed it to that and still got the error... I don't have a lot of experience in ajax

Comment: What is the error ? Please see error on browser console.

Comment: Please click on the error in console to see details. and post it here